# Installing 3.5inch rpi display on windows 10 iot

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I need some help installing 3.5inch rpi display on raspberry pi 3 .. I searched in the internet but all I found is some commands to install it on rasbian .. thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the display in the [Hardware compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist).
The displays on this list is verified by Microsoft,they can work fine with Windows IoT Core. If you want to install another display which not in the list,perhaps you need to implement the driver.

Comment: thnx i coudn't find mine in that list .. this is the link of the driver https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show .. how can i install it in windows iot ??

Comment: The driver in the repo you mentioned above is for Raspbian, it does not support Windows IoT Core. It is recommended to use the display in the compatibility list to replace this 3.5inch device.